# Symfony2 : How to remove form field in listener, after submit

Tags: forms, symfony, events, field, listener

Im facing a problem in a FormType I have.
based on the "Product" entity, this from has a field called "ProductCriteria", which is a collection based on "ProductCriteriaType" (Form).

My productCriteria Model hold a "deleted" attribute that handles the logic suppression of this entity. If it is set to true, then i dont want the productCriteria form type to be display in the product Form Type. If it is set to false, then i want to display it in the product Form Type, you get it.

I have written this in the PRE_SET_DATA event of my form, which works incredibly well:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $product = $event->getData();


        /** @var PersistentCollection $productCriteriasFields */
        $productCriteriasFields = $product->getProductCriterias();

        /** @var ProductCriteria $productCriteria */
        foreach($productCriteriasFields as $productCriteria){
            if($productCriteria->getDeleted()){
                $productCriteriasFields->removeElement($productCriteria);
            }
        }

    });
```

My fields are set to true/false in the form and when I access the FormType it doesnt display the delete-true one as expected.

THE ONLY PROBLEM IS:
When I just modified a 'deleted' value, the controller doesnt redirect to another page when the form isValid(). It just renders the FormType again, and the form DOESNT CONTAIN MY MODIFICATIONS (but they are in DB !). If I refresh the page (F5), I have in deed the modifications I want.
How to solve this ? I tried to add a 'POST_SUBMIT' function, working on the form fields like this:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event){

                    /** @var Product $data */
                    $product = $event->getForm()->getData(); //this was supposed to do the trick
                    $form = $event->getForm();

                /** @var ProductCriteria $productCriteria */
                for($i = 0; $i < count($product->getProductCriterias()); $i++){
                    if($product->getProductCriterias()[$i]->getDeleted()){
                        ladybug_dump("unsetting one field ! ");
                        unset($form->get('productCriterias')[$i]);
                    }
                }
```

But nothing works. Any idea? Thanks a LOT.

EDIT
Controller's code (it is an abstracted one: archi of my project, not a choice):

```
/** @var EditableEntityInterface $entity */
$entity = $this->entityService->getEntityById($itemId);
$form = $this->createForm('admin' . $this->entityService->getEntityName(), $entity);

$form->handleRequest($this->get('request'));
$submitSuccess = false;
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $this->entityService->save($form->getData());
    $submitSuccess = true;
}

$template = $this->getActionTemplate($this->entityService->getEditTemplate());

return $this->render($template, array(
    'item' => $entity,
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'entityService' => $this->entityService,
    'submitSuccess' => $submitSuccess
));
```

Comment: can you show us controller action code?

Comment: instead of this" /** @var Product $data */
                    $product = $event->getForm()->getData(); //this was supposed to do the trick
                    $form = $event->getForm();"
try this:
$form = $event->getForm();
$data = $event->getData();

Comment: Already tried, doesnt work. The part that concerns me is:

if($product->getProductCriterias()[$i]->getDeleted()){
                        ladybug_dump("unsetting one field ! ");
                        unset($form->get('productCriterias')[$i]);
                    }

Comment: I'm not sure about how to delete subforms in a collection field and I suspect my controller to take the previous entity-data

Comment: Have you tried $form->remove('field_name'); to remove field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i finally got the thing to work !! The problem was in deed from my controller code in which i modified:

```
$form->handleRequest($this->get('request'));
$submitSuccess = false;
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $this->entityService->save($form->getData());
    $submitSuccess = true;
// Data sync hardened !
            $entity = $this->entityService->getEntityById($itemId);
            $form = $this->createForm('admin' . $this->entityService->getEntityName(), $entity);
}
```

I forced the form to be re-hydrated by the entity we just save, to ensure it doesnt take previous datas in the previous $request.
But still... this is incredible I couldn't achieve this by using form event. The doc is horribly poor, and shows only very simple examples. For those who might neet more info on form event, i can recommand this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#component-form-event-table
and have a look at this class in the core:
Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\EventListener\ResizeFormListener.php
thats pretty much everything you can do on forms with the main FormEvents.